# Watch variable outside angularJS

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, auth0

So I'm working on an Ionic HTML5 Hybrid app.  I'm using Firebase to store data and Auth0 for authentication.  Everything has gone very smoothly, but I've hit a little snag that I can't seem to figure out because my newbiness to AngularJS.  It seems I should be using $apply here, but the docs are pretty confusing in this regard and I can't figure it out.

I have a view in which I want the user to be able to link the social auth accounts that aren't already linked to their account.  It works by checking which auth providers are within the profile of that user.  The HTML is below:

```
<ion-view title="Account">
  <ion-content class="has-header padding">
    <button class="button button-block button-positive icon-left icon ion-social-facebook" ng-if="facebookCheck() == false" ng-click="linkFacebook()"> Add Facebook Account</button>
    <button class="button button-block button-calm icon-left icon ion-social-twitter" ng-if="twitterCheck() == false" ng-click="linkTwitter()"> Add Twitter Account</button>
    <button class="button button-block button-dark icon-left icon ion-social-instagram" ng-if="instagramCheck() == false" ng-click="linkInstagram()"> Add Instagram Account</button>
    <br>  
    <button class="button button-assertive button-block" ng-click="logout()">Logout</button>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Here is the controller.  This works exactly as I want it to if you logout or close the app and reopen, but I want it to watch for changes in auth.profile so after a user logs in to one of the available providers and returns to the view, the button to login with that provider will disappear from the view.

```
.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope, auth, $state, store) {

  $scope.logout = function() {
    auth.signout();
    store.remove('token');
    store.remove('profile');
    store.remove('refreshToken');
    $state.go('login');
  }

  $scope.profile = auth.profile;

  $scope.facebookCheck = function() {
     for (i = 0; i < $scope.profile.identities.length; i++) {
        if (angular.equals($scope.profile.identities[i].provider, "facebook")) {
                     return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
};

   $scope.twitterCheck = function() {
     for (i = 0; i < $scope.profile.identities.length; i++) {
        if (angular.equals($scope.profile.identities[i].provider, "twitter")) {
                     return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
};

   $scope.instagramCheck = function() {
     for (i = 0; i < $scope.profile.identities.length; i++) {
        if (angular.equals($scope.profile.identities[i].provider, "instagram")) {
                     return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
};

  $scope.linkTwitter = function () {
    var lock = new Auth0Lock('ywxuAvQN38sQqiiwYz3CJ3IsPUiEg94x', 'fanzee.auth0.com');

    lock.show({
      dict: {
        signin: {
          title: 'Link another account'
        }
      },
      connections: ['twitter'],
      authParams: {
        access_token: auth.accessToken
      }
    })
};

  $scope.linkFacebook = function () {
    var lock = new Auth0Lock('ywxuAvQN38sQqiiwYz3CJ3IsPUiEg94x', 'fanzee.auth0.com');

    lock.show({
      dict: {
        signin: {
          title: 'Link another account'
        }
      },
      connections: ['facebook'],
      authParams: {
        access_token: auth.accessToken
      }
    })
};

  $scope.linkInstagram = function () {
    var lock = new Auth0Lock('ywxuAvQN38sQqiiwYz3CJ3IsPUiEg94x', 'fanzee.auth0.com');

    lock.show({
      dict: {
        signin: {
          title: 'Link another account'
        }
      },
      connections: ['instagram'],
      authParams: {
        access_token: auth.accessToken
      }
    })
};
```

I know a lot of this could be in a service, but I was moving things around to try and get this working properly.  What should I be doing here?  How do I get Angular to watch for changes to auth.profile?  Thanks.

Comment: Please create plunkar or fiddle

Comment: I'm not sure how I can create a functional plunker/fiddle/codepen in this case without including some details I'm not quite comfortable publishing here with the current security rules I've included in Auth0.  If it's not clear, the auth.profile object is updated outside of Angular, by the Auth0 service, and I'm trying to make sure Angular watches for changes in that object so when the functions checking for auth wiith the services below (facebookCheck(), twitterCheck(), etc.) iterate over profile.identies, that object will be up to date.

Comment: Why don't you use an event emitter? You can emit an event when the auth.profile changes, and in your controller you can listen to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see here, we emit an event when the profile changes, and then we catch it on our controller. If we remove the event catcher part, the profile will change when we click the button, but the `$scope.profile` value will not be updated.

See this Plunker: [Example Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1Xxl5jqLjB1y5HYlXLGQ?p=preview)

Comment: This works perfectly.  Thanks!  I'm having trouble finding information on emitters in the docs.  Could you possibly point me in the right direction to learn more about this?

Comment: You should look for it in the scope docs, here the listener documentation link: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on

Comment: Great, just what I needed.  Thanks!